# Javascript - email validation does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML script with CSS and Javascript in it. I have a simple javascript function which should validate the email I have entered. But the javascript function does not get called at all. Can someone help ?

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("email").value;
  alert(x);
  var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>DELIVERY DETAILS</h1>

<form id="deliveryDetails">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br> e-mail:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="email"><br> telephone number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telephone number"><br> order number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="order number"><br> order date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="order date"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onsumbmit="return validateForm();">

</form>
```

Comment: I upvote you because this question is so cute for answering. your code style is a little old and can be in new styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submit button does not have an `onsubmit` event, the form does, add the event to the form instead, and the code does get executed:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("email").value;
  alert(x);
  var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>DELIVERY DETAILS</h1>

<form id="deliveryDetails" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br> e-mail:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="email"><br> telephone number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telephone number"><br> order number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="order number"><br> order date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="order date"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: @ashani123, yeah it works but your code is not optimized.

Comment: @AmerllicA is right, you should also check out the other answers.

Comment: @Luca, Absolutely you deserved to have tick mark, but I'm very sensitive on code optimization. that code has no _pure function_ and is written like legacy codes.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, I believe you can use `HTML5` advantage, you can use `input` `email` type and use `CSS` for its validation:

```
<input class="email" type="email"/>
```

And put related `CSS` for `valid` or `invalid`:

```
.email:valid {
    color: green; //for example
}

.email:invalid {
    color: red; //for example
}
```

But in your case, I don't read your function, and I don't know why you do not use `RegExp` for check validation.

You can bind a click event to your submit button:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

And for attaching click event:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener(`click`,() => {
    validateForm();
}, false);
```

Your `validateForm` is not optimized. you can write is like below:

```
const validForm = (emailString) => {
    return /^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_\.]+@([a-z]|[a-z0-9]?[a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9])\.[a-z0-9]{2,10}(?:\.[a-z]{2,10})?$/.test(emailString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onsumbmit="return validateForm();"`

On sumbmit? You've invented a word there. In any case, that event won't fire the function, because `onsumbmit` isn't a valid event.

Also, put the event on the form (which 'owns' the event), not the button. i.e.

`<form id="deliveryDetails" onsubmit="return validateForm();">`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the type to email without any extra validation code e.g

```
<input type="email"  required/>
```

Or use regex

```
        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }

    function validate() {
      var email = $("#email").val();

      if (validateEmail(email)) {

      }

$("#validate").bind("click", validate);
```

HTML

```
<form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input type="text" id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should then also set the email input to required, because otherwise you can just not enter an email at all

Answer (score 0):

Use the `button type ="submit"` & prevent the default behavior of the button using `preventDefault`

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>DELIVERY DETAILS</h1>
<form id="deliveryDetails">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br> e-mail:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="email"><br> telephone number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telephone number"><br> order number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="order number"><br> order date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="order date"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="validateForm(event)">Submit</button>
</form>
```